# Should I know who Prentice/Prentiss is by the time I listen to Magnus Archives episode 6?

Tags: horror, podcast, the-magnus-archives

I've recently listened to the 6th episode of The Magnus Archives (Squirm), and the narrator mentions Prentice (or Prentiss) in the closing statement.

The way it's phrased made me think they'd already been mentioned in the podcast, but I can't recall any mention.

Is this the first reference? Or should I have heard of them from an earlier episode or elsewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the first reference to [Jane Prentiss](https://the-magnus-archives.fandom.com/wiki/Jane_Prentiss).

> Jonathan Sims remarks that the attack matches the description and last known location of one Jane Prentiss. John reported Timothy to the ECDC (The European Centre for Disease Prevention and Control) and says that he hopes they catch up to Timothy sooner rather than later.

She gets more fleshing out in later episodes:

> - Episode 32
>  - Episode 39
>  - Episode 55
>  - Episode 118
>  - Episode 152
>  - Episode 160

Comment: Ah, that matches what I remember but I couldn't confirm that was her first appearance. Thanks!